# How to merge a branch into master without changes?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-extensions

I want to merge integration branch into master, but I don't want to change anything only to look good.

Integration branch is that with gray. This branch contains a lot of changes, and I want to make a trick. To reset it, when was splitted from master, because I can saw last changes and put them with one commit on master. So master will contain last version of files from integration branch, but integration will remain splitted from master.

I want to merge integration into master, only visual (without changes), to look good on history, because I already have changes with that single commit.

[image]

**The final question is: How to merge integration in master without to put changes on master, only to affect history (visually)?**

**I want to do that BECAUSE:**

- after I split integration from master project structure was modified and now I have to much conflicts. It's more easier to make merge manually. After that I only want to "merge" integration on master without to put changes (because already are there).

Comment: This isn't clear - are you saying you've already squashed/rebased the changes onto `master`?

Comment: Try `git merge -s ours`

Comment: It is very clear, I write there that I reset integration in the point when it was splitted from master, so I have the last files version. And that changes I manually put on master (in visual studio). After that I want to "merge" integration into master only to look good.

Comment: It sounds like you want to checkout integration, soft reset to commit 2, and stash the changes, checkout master, and then pop the stash. --- You're still going to have conflicts, and you might as well just merge normally.

Comment: I have, but I can put last changes in one move. Not commit by commit from integration. The final question is: How to merge integration in master without to put changes on master, only to affect history (visually)

Comment: If it were clear, I wouldn't have said "this isn't clear" (and you also wouldn't have received an answer that "isn't the answer for my question") :/  It's still unclear to me why you don't just do a normal merge.

Comment: because integration is so advanced in time, and took me to long to make that merge, manually with reset took me only 10 minutes, because I had last version, and now I want to merge without changes.

Comment: I have 100 commits on Integration, and too more 20 on master from that point when I spit them

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way that I did it. This assumes we are on `current-branch` and will merge `branch-to-merge` into our current branch (`current-branch`).

First:

```sh
git merge branch-to-merge
```

At this point, if we get a merge conflict, just commit everything including the conflicts without fixing them, it won't matter. So if we have a conflict, just commit it anyway:

```sh
git add every thing
git commit # conclude the merge, don't worry about conflict markers
```

Now let's get the commit hash of this new merge commit. Run

```sh
git log
```

to see the history and copy the hash of the merge commit. Suppose this commit is `12345abc`. Now we will reset our `current-branch` back to our previous commit from before the merge, so that we get the files back into the state we want:

```sh
git reset HEAD~ --hard
```

This brings our branch to exactly the same state we started in. If we look around (f.e. see `git log`), we will see that we undid the merge commit and went back to our previous commit.

But!

That merge commit is still stored in git's internal history. Now, let's bring back that commit (`12345abc` in this example), without changing the contents of our files, so that our files stay in the same state just as we desire:

```sh
git reset 12345abc --soft
```

Now, if we run `git status`, we will see that there are staged changes. These changes are our original commit's files, exactly as we want them!

Now, let's amend the merge commit so it has our original set of files:

```sh
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

This last command overwrote the current commit (which happens to be the merge commit) using `--amend`, rather than making a new commit, and because our original commit's file state was in place, git replaced the merge commit's files with our previous commit's files. Great!

The `--no-edit` flag specified to just keep the same commit message.

Done!

I haven't tried @SethRobertson's approach, and it may work fine, but I like my approach because it is less scripty and uses a series of basic commands to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'll agree that under almost all circumstances you should not do what the OP is asking, but I do believe that there are times when it does make sense.  I won't bore you with my reasons to avoid arguments about version control purity.

There are a number of ways of doing this, but here is one.  Note that this command gives you to the power to really mess your life (git history) up, so be careful.

```
git reset "$(git commit-tree -p "$BRANCH_NO_CONTENT_CHANGE" -p "$BRANCH_PRETENDING_TO_MERGE_FROM" -m "Administrative (no-change) merge of $BRANCH_PRETENDING_TO_MERGE_FROM" "$(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%T "$BRANCH_NO_CONTENT_CHANGE")")"
```

In the context of the OP, `BRANCH_NO_CONTENT_CHANGE` is master and `BRANCH_PRETENDING_TO_MERGE_FROM` is integration.

I've also used this in "reverse" where I have a magic branch where magic things happen and I want to make the content of the magic branch identical to the donor branch (change the last instance of last variable appearing to the other name, change the merge commit message s/no-change/overwrite/, and ignore the semantics of the names).  Kind of like a force push except preserving history.

I strongly suggest careful checking of what files are where with what name and content along with testing **before** pushing these change and concretizing your sin for eternity.

Answer (score 0):

The steps you need to do in order to achieve this are:

- checkout integration branch
- do a rebase with master (git pull --rebase master)
- push integration branch
- checkout master
- merge integration branch
- push master branch.

But this will work only if integration is not a public branch. If it is, then you will rewrite its history and is not a good thing. If its public, then the only thing you can do is merge it with master, but you won't have a linear history.

Comment: If the integration branch contains the same changes as have already been placed onto master, then the rebase will produce 0 commits.

Comment: This isn't the answer for my question, because if I rebase integration on master I would have conflicts. When I soft reset integration will remain unstaged files, I will make changes manually, and after that I want to fake a merge between integration and master, only to look good.

Comment: I have totally different file paths, and file content.

Comment: @Alex - This use-case doesn't really make sense.  Why don't you want to do a **real** merge?

Comment: Because are to many conflicts. I change files location and if I want to merge it would throw me the popup with keep ours, delete their, keep base file. I don't want to keep any file, and if I delete a file I will lose changes (poor git merge), If I reset it, I have last version of files (what I want, but I want to merge it without to change anything on master). How to merge without to change something on master? only to look visually good.

If I put manually last version of files, it will took me 5 minutes, If I need to merge I have a lot of popups, merges and conflicts, it will took me 1h

Comment: @Alex If you don't want the merge to change anything, then why do a merge at all?